# Method not found error after updating Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, restful-authentication

it's about Ruby On Rails and it's Restful Authentication plugin.

I updated Rails.
I restarted my WebApp.

> The method "store_location" of Restful
>   Authentication cannot be found. in the
>   file lib/restful_authentication.rb can
>   the method be found, by me, but no
>   longer by Rails.

Why?

Comment: Did you try to update the plugin? What versions (Rails, restful_authentication) are you using?

Comment: all the newest. updating did not help.

Comment: I guess I better change to a Google login...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a tough spot. The restful-authentication plugin hasn't been updated in a while, so it is best to leave it and move to something else. The likelihood of getting old (6+ months old) gems and plugins to work becomes exponentially unlikely.

Check out [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) - it should provide what you need.